# Why function is evaluated backward?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a simple function:

`f[x0_,y0_]:= Module[{x=x0,y=y0},For[i=0,i<2,i++;Print[x],Print[x+y]];]`

So when I call it:
`f[2,3]`

I get:

> 5
>   2
>   5
>   2

Why not:

> 2
>   5
>   2
>   5

as expected?  Also my indentation of - or + don't seem to format?

Comment: Try `f[x0_, y0_] :=  Module[{x = x0, y = y0},For[i = 0, i < 2,i++;Print[x]; Print[x + y]];]`. This works as you expect it to work.

Comment: Hi @Öskå Thanks, but is the semicolon not the standard way of suppressing an output, anyway it works but I can't figure out why comma reverses the order and semicolon works?

Comment: The `Print` function will print whether you add a `;` in the end or not. Although I have no clue why that comma changes the order.

Comment: With the comma the first print is evaluated during incrementation, and not in the body. Hence the reversed order. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SequencesOfOperations.html

Answer (score 8):

`For` syntax is like this:

```
For[start,test,incr,body]
```

Your first `Print` is part of the incrementation step, due to `;` combining it into one expression

```
For[i = 0, i <= 3, Print["incrementing from ",i]; i++, Print[i]]
(* Result:
0
incrementing from 0
1
incrementing from 1
2
incrementing from 2
3
incrementing from 3
*)
```

You can put it all in the body like (note position of commas and semicolons):

```
For[i = 0, i < 2,i++,Print[x]; Print[x + y]]
```

I recommend you actively try to avoid `For` loops when coding in Mathematica, see for instance [Functional Programming: Quick Start](http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/dev001.html).

And check the other links in [this popular answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259) under the section *Basic advices for people new to Mathematica*